# When I try to activate a virtual environment with venv I get an error

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-venv

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.atlantic.net/cloud-hosting/how-to-manage-python-virtual-environments/) on how to set up a virtual environment in Python3.6 using the windows command prompt. I had no problem generating the necessary file by running this:

```
python3 -m venv venv-test
```

The tutorial then advises to activate the virtual environment by running this code:

```
venv-test/Scripts/activate
```

But when I do this , I get the error...

```
 File "venv-test/Scripts/activate", line 4
    deactivate () {
              ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I opened the generated 'activate' file and this seems to be the part that's causing the problem but I'm not sure how to correct it.

```
deactivate () {
# reset old environment variables
if [ -n "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH:-}" ] ; then
    PATH="${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH:-}"
    export PATH
    unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH
fi
if [ -n "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME:-}" ] ; then
    PYTHONHOME="${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME:-}"
    export PYTHONHOME
    unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME
fi
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide all necessary information in your question. External links may go offline, rendering your question useless to people coming here in the future

Comment: You got quite a few answers, and you also answered your question yourself. Please don't forget to accept an answer (tick the check-mark next to an answer) if it answers your question. In this way your question stops from showing up as unanswered in the question searches. After a 2-days wait period you can also accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

`source venv-test/bin/activate`

It worked here. Make sure you're in the folder that contains your venv, otherwise just mention its full path.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't got access to a windows machine at the moment but if I remember correctly you need to run activate.bat and I think you need the full path.

So something like:

```
C://code/project/venv-test/Scripts/activate.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

On Python 3.8 just go to the folder containing the virtual environment and type

```
source venv-test\scripts\activate
```

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happen to me with one environment, and just adding ./ to the begining of the path solved it. So in your case it would be

```
./venv-test/Scripts/activate
```

instead of

```
venv-test/Scripts/activate
```

Comment: This worked for me, I was in the Script folder and "activate" is giving me the OP's error. It's worked with past environments, but not this one. Using ./activate works for some reason, which is a pain, but it'll do for now.

Answer (score 0):

not sure the reason why running

```
venv-test/Scripts/activate
```

doesn't work but if you go into the directory venv-test/Scripts and THEN type activate it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

change directory to scripts directory as follows:

```
cd venv-test/Scripts
```

and run the activate file by typing

```
activate
```

at the prompt

Comment: thank you for sharing your information. it seems you are new. please see this link to see how to write a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

you have to run source venv-test/bin/activate not venv-test/Scripts/activate

Comment: Please explain how your post differs from a copy of the upvoted already existing answer by Luiz Gabriel. I do not see it.

Answer (score 0):

---

I had the same problem before, try typing :

```
venv-test/Scripts/activate.bat,
```

it worked for me